# Urls in restful webservices

Tags: c#, java, web-services, rest

I have read this ebook and I've read that you should try to limit yourself to two base URLs.
So if you have a quiz resouce you would have `/quizes` and `/quizes/{id}`. Then you use the HTTP verbs for actions. However how would you get a quiz from the server which is dynamically made with random questions when you try to follow this pattern?

I thougth of `/quizes?type=random`, but let say you want the type attribute to be optional defaulting to random and you already use the `/quizes` path for listing all saved quizes.

Creating a `/quizes/generate?type=random` path isn't following the advices, nor do I think the generate term fits in since it is a verb.

And are paths such as `/quizes` "reserved" to returning collections (I know REST isn't a spec) or is it perfectly legal to use `/quizes` for generating a quiz server side and returning it?

http://apigee.com/about/content/web-api-design

Comment: This is a legitimate question on REST. Why has it been closed?

Comment: @VivinPaliath best practices questions are typically too subjective. Not sure about this one, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak This didn't seem like a best-practices question but a question on how to implement this in a REST way.

Answer (score 1):

What `/quizzes` should do is provide you a list of URL's that let you access different quizzes, so let's say you have defined that the media-type that `/quizzes` returns is JSON like so (maybe a specific type like `application/json+quiz`):

```
{ 
    quizzes = [
        { description: "Quiz 1", url: "/quizzes/1" },
        { description: "Quiz 2", url: "/quizzes/2" }
    ]
}
```

So what you can have is an entry that lets you access a random quiz, that can be something like this:

```
{ 
    quizzes = [
        { description: "Quiz 1", url: "/quizzes/1" },
        { description: "Quiz 2", url: "/quizzes/2" },
        { description: "Random", url: "/quizzes/random" },
    ]
}
```

The idea is that there is one REST endpoint, and all subsequent URL's are discovered through semantic media-types. So if your media-type specifies that there will be an entry with description `Random` that will give you a random quiz, then the endpoint consumer can use it.